# ScrollMagic bugs setPin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scrollmagic

I have bugs with Scroll Magic, I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PageScroll Test</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
    <style>

        .content {
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .block-news {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            /*margin-top: -100%;*/
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .news {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            z-index: 10;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 0 !important;
            background: #ffffff;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="block-news"><h1>ONE</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi consequuntur est facilis inventore iste
            maiores nostrum sunt ullam, velit! At autem cum cumque debitis eos excepturi itaque iure laboriosam maxime
            molestiae necessitatibus neque nihil, obcaecati odio pariatur, quam ratione sequi, sint. Ab aliquid aperiam
            architecto asperiores assumenda at consequuntur corporis delectus distinctio doloremque, ducimus eos esse
            eum expedita fugiat harum impedit in, labore laborum magnam neque non officia pariatur quis quisquam saepe
            tempore temporibus ullam vel voluptatibus? Consequuntur deleniti dicta dolorem eligendi eum facilis fugiat
            illo molestias obcaecati, odit omnis optio pariatur praesentium quod repellendus reprehenderit, ullam ut.
            Assumenda at autem, blanditiis commodi debitis dolorem ea error facilis fuga fugiat harum hic, illum ipsum
            iste iure nam natus odio omnis pariatur placeat quae soluta temporibus veniam? Animi aperiam aspernatur
            consectetur cum cumque, cupiditate est illum inventore ipsum iste laudantium libero nam non odit provident
            quae quidem quod rem tempora voluptates!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad adipisci commodi consequatur, dignissimos dolor
            hic ipsum nostrum odit optio provident quaerat quas quasi quibusdam quis quisquam ratione velit veniam?
            Autem, rem, voluptatem? Alias animi aperiam corporis dignissimos dolore ea eligendi error esse excepturi
            illo iste iure iusto labore laudantium necessitatibus nemo obcaecati officia optio, quae rem, rerum sunt
            tenetur unde velit voluptatem voluptatibus voluptatum. Accusamus accusantium ad at commodi consequuntur
            corporis cupiditate dolorem doloremque ducimus ea et explicabo incidunt itaque laudantium, nobis pariatur
            perspiciatis, quae quaerat quod rem repellat reprehenderit sequi vitae! Aliquam commodi, cupiditate dolorem
            expedita labore laborum maxime nulla placeat possimus quaerat quos reiciendis, saepe soluta tenetur ut! A ad
            aspernatur at aut consectetur consequuntur cum dolore doloremque, et eum, excepturi, facere impedit iste
            iure libero nobis numquam odio provident qui quia reiciendis sint sit tempora tempore totam velit veniam
            voluptatibus? Earum eius quod reiciendis suscipit ut voluptate?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="block-news"><h1>ONE</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi consequuntur est facilis inventore iste
            maiores nostrum sunt ullam, velit! At autem cum cumque debitis eos excepturi itaque iure laboriosam maxime
            molestiae necessitatibus neque nihil, obcaecati odio pariatur, quam ratione sequi, sint. Ab aliquid aperiam
            architecto asperiores assumenda at consequuntur corporis delectus distinctio doloremque, ducimus eos esse
            eum expedita fugiat harum impedit in, labore laborum magnam neque non officia pariatur quis quisquam saepe
            tempore temporibus ullam vel voluptatibus? Consequuntur deleniti dicta dolorem eligendi eum facilis fugiat
            illo molestias obcaecati, odit omnis optio pariatur praesentium quod repellendus reprehenderit, ullam ut.
            Assumenda at autem, blanditiis commodi debitis dolorem ea error facilis fuga fugiat harum hic, illum ipsum
            iste iure nam natus odio omnis pariatur placeat quae soluta temporibus veniam? Animi aperiam aspernatur
            consectetur cum cumque, cupiditate est illum inventore ipsum iste laudantium libero nam non odit provident
            quae quidem quod rem tempora voluptates!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad adipisci commodi consequatur, dignissimos dolor
            hic ipsum nostrum odit optio provident quaerat quas quasi quibusdam quis quisquam ratione velit veniam?
            Autem, rem, voluptatem? Alias animi aperiam corporis dignissimos dolore ea eligendi error esse excepturi
            illo iste iure iusto labore laudantium necessitatibus nemo obcaecati officia optio, quae rem, rerum sunt
            tenetur unde velit voluptatem voluptatibus voluptatum. Accusamus accusantium ad at commodi consequuntur
            corporis cupiditate dolorem doloremque ducimus ea et explicabo incidunt itaque laudantium, nobis pariatur
            perspiciatis, quae quaerat quod rem repellat reprehenderit sequi vitae! Aliquam commodi, cupiditate dolorem
            expedita labore laborum maxime nulla placeat possimus quaerat quos reiciendis, saepe soluta tenetur ut! A ad
            aspernatur at aut consectetur consequuntur cum dolore doloremque, et eum, excepturi, facere impedit iste
            iure libero nobis numquam odio provident qui quia reiciendis sint sit tempora tempore totam velit veniam
            voluptatibus? Earum eius quod reiciendis suscipit ut voluptate?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aspernatur autem deleniti, dolor est iure
            iusto nisi repellat rerum? At et officia repellendus sunt voluptates. Labore minus nemo, nisi numquam omnis
            quod ut. Accusamus asperiores aut commodi dolor, et iste laborum necessitatibus nobis pariatur quaerat
            ratione ullam vero voluptates. Alias consequuntur cupiditate dicta, eveniet explicabo iste laboriosam,
            laudantium nihil nostrum numquam obcaecati sint tempora temporibus. Ab adipisci atque commodi consequatur
            deleniti ducimus expedita explicabo fuga hic itaque, magni maiores neque obcaecati porro quibusdam quis
            sequi sit vero. Architecto, debitis distinctio dolor dolore doloribus hic inventore ipsa, provident rem
            reprehenderit sapiente sequi, sint! Alias asperiores aut eligendi, eum ex illo laudantium molestias mollitia
            numquam repudiandae soluta sunt ullam ut. Accusantium consequatur delectus facere ipsa labore magni
            molestiae nemo nesciunt, nobis non optio quam quo reiciendis, saepe similique vel voluptatum. Aliquid amet
            consectetur deserunt dignissimos doloribus ducimus fugiat incidunt, perferendis ratione.</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var processing;

    $(document).scroll(function (e) {

        if (processing)
            return false;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.9) {
            processing = true;


            $.post('test.php', function (data) {
                $('.content').html('<div class="block-news">' + data + '</div>');
                $('.content .block-news').each(function () {

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var tween = TweenMax.from($(this), 1, {backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)", opacity: 0, ease: Ease.easeNone});
                    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({

                        triggerElement: this,
                        duration: '50%',
                        offset: 100 + "%"

                    })

                        .on("enter", function (e) {
                            $(this).css("z-index", "5");
                        })
                        .on("leave", function (e) {
                            $(this).css("z-index", "9")
                        })
                        .setPin(this , {pushFollowers: 0})
                        .setTween(tween)
                        .addTo(controller)
                        .addIndicators();
                });
                processing = false;
            });

        }


    });

    $('.block-news').each(function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        var tween = TweenMax.from($(this), 1, {backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)", opacity: 0, ease: Ease.easeNone});
        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({

            triggerElement: this,
            duration: 70 + "%",
            offset: 100 + "%"

        })

            .on("enter", function (e) {
                $(this).css("z-index", "5");
            })
            .on("leave", function (e) {
                $(this).css("z-index", "9")
            })
            .setPin(this)
            .setTween(tween)
            .addTo(controller)
            .addIndicators();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i scroll down full height of document, load new div with data via $.post request from another document or PHP
file
I Need to Pin ajax loaded div with scrollmagic plugin, when user scroll up full height of this div, unpined it, and Pin next.

DEMO: http://185.154.52.186/

Please Help!